# How to create a weight adaptive network in keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I would like to make a simple model in keras with few dense layers where the weights and biases of the first layer can be created by another model. something similar to [this paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/e7e23670481ac78b3c4122a99ba60573-Paper.pdf) but more simple, where the CNN is also replaced with dense layers.

I tried this:

```
aux_in = np.random.random((2000, 10)) # features to generate weights
data_in = np.random.random((2000, 40))# main features
target = np.random.random((2000, 4))# annotations to be predicted

def create_ws(dim1,dim2):
    # define our MLP network
    model = Sequential()
    initializer = RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.)
    model.add(Dense(dim2, input_dim=dim1, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    return model

def create_FCN(dim,ws):
    # define our MLP network
    model = Sequential()
    initializer = RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.)
    model.add(Dense(128, 
                    input_dim=dim, 
                    activation="sigmoid",
                    kernel_initializer=initializer
                    ))
    model.set_weights(ws)
    return model


wgen = create_ws(aux_in.shape[1],data_in.shape[1])
mainf = create_FCN(data_in.shape[1], wgen.get_weights()[2:])

x = Dense(32, activation="sigmoid")(mainf.output)
x = Dense(4, activation="linear")(x)
main_model = Model(inputs=[mainf.input, wgen.input], outputs=x)
opt = Nadam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(x=[data_in,aux_in], y=target, validation_split=0.1, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

The issue is, the "wgen" model seems to be detached from the "main_model", such that its' weights remain the same before and after training "main_model".
The connection between "mainf" and "main_model" seems to be correct because when I check the weights on the "main_model" before and after training, it is clear that they are being updated.

How should I rewire this model in order to include the weight generating network("wgen") into the main model pipeline?